# How to check if a class already exists in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

How do I check if a class already exists in Ruby?

My code is:

```
puts "enter the name of the Class to see if it exists"   
nameofclass=gets.chomp  
eval (" #{nameofclass}......  Not sure what to write here")
```

I was thinking of using:

```
eval "#{nameofclass}ancestors.     ....."
```

Answer (score 88):

You can use `Module.const_get` to get the constant referred to by the string. It will return the constant (generally classes are referenced by constants). You can then check to see if the constant is a class.

I would do something along these lines:

```
def class_exists?(class_name)
  klass = Module.const_get(class_name)
  return klass.is_a?(Class)
rescue NameError
  return false
end
```

Also, if possible I would always avoid using `eval` when accepting user input; I doubt this is going to be used for any serious application, but worth being aware of the security risks.

Comment: For me, it was good if the named thing was a Module as well.  Used `klass.is_a?(Class) || klass.is_a?(Module)`. A namespace qualified name worked with this method. For example `class_exists?('Delayed::Worker')`  Very nice.

Answer (score 55):

perhaps you can do it with defined?

eg:

```
if defined?(MyClassName) == 'constant' && MyClassName.class == Class  
   puts "its a class" 
end
```

Note: the Class check is required, for example:

```
Hello = 1 
puts defined?(Hello) == 'constant' # returns true
```

To answer the original question:

```
puts "enter the name of the Class to see if it exists"
nameofclass=gets.chomp
eval("defined?(#{nameofclass}) == 'constant' and #{nameofclass}.class == Class")
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Lot of cases in gems you need to do things like this as well. defined? ::Rails

Comment: `defined?(MyClassName) == 'constant' && MyClassName.is_a?(Class)` looks more intuitive.

Comment: Why `defined? Object.const_get("array".capitalize)` is returning "method", while i run `defined? Array` return "constant" ?

Comment: Just a warning from some recent problems with this, defined? will throw an error if MyClassName does not exist. At least in current versions of Ruby. For more info you can check out the docs: (http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F)

Comment: ```
irb(main):003:0> defined? TestingTesting::Testing
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.6.1"
```

Comment: Note, it may return nil when autoload not yet loaded class in Rails

Answer (score 32):

You can avoid having to rescue the NameError from `Module.const_get` if you are looking the constant within a certain scope by calling `Module#const_defined?("SomeClass")`.

A common scope to call this would be Object, eg: `Object.const_defined?("User")`.

See: "[Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001691)".

Comment: this will only return true if the class has been loaded.

    >> Object.const_defined?("MyClass") # false
    >> MyClass # MyClass
    >> Object.const_defined?("MyClass") # true

this is at least the case in a Rails console, YMMV.

Answer (score 11):

Class names are constants. You can use the `defined?` method to see if a constant has been defined.

```
defined?(String)    # => "constant"
defined?(Undefined) # => nil
```

You can read more about how [`defined?`](http://redhanded.hobix.com/inspect/methodCheckDefined.html) works if you're interested.

Comment: This will not work for defined? 'String', though, which really was the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
defined?(DatabaseCleaner) # => nil
require 'database_cleaner'
defined?(DatabaseCleaner) # => constant
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Kernel.const_defined?("Fixnum") # => true
```

Comment: This will only return true only if the class has been loaded 

```$ rails c test
Loading test environment (Rails 4.2.5.1)
2.2.1 :001 > Kernel.const_defined?('ApiProvider')
 => false 
2.2.1 :002 > ApiProvider
 => ApiProvider 
2.2.1 :003 > Kernel.const_defined?('ApiProvider')
 => true 
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's something I sometimes do to tackle this very issue. You can add the following methods to the String class like so:

```
class String
    def to_class
        my_const = Kernel.const_get(self)
        my_const.is_a?(Class) ? my_const : nil
    rescue NameError 
        nil
    end

    def is_a_defined_class?
        true if self.to_class
    rescue NameError
        false
    end
end
```

Then:

```
'String'.to_class
=> String
'unicorn'.to_class
=> nil
'puppy'.is_a_defined_class?
=> false
'Fixnum'.is_a_defined_class?
=> true
```

Comment: This is a really cool way of going about this, especially if you're dealing with user input in the form of strings (ex Rails).  Thanks for this cool idea!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more succinct version:

```
def class_exists?(class_name)
  eval("defined?(#{class_name}) && #{class_name}.is_a?(Class)") == true
end

class_name = "Blorp"
class_exists?(class_name)
=> false

class_name = "String"
class_exists?(class_name)
=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

In just one line, I would write:

```
!!Module.const_get(nameofclass) rescue false
```

that will return `true`only if the given `nameofclass` belongs to a defined class.

Comment: That will return true for any constant in Module (which may be all, I don't know), not just for classes. `Bla="some string" ; !!Module.const_get(:Bla) rescue false` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a simple standalone class e.g.

```rb
class Foo
end
```

then we can use `Object.const_defined?("Foo")`. And, if your class is inside any module e.g.

```rb
module Bar
  class Foo
  end
end
```

then we can use `Module.const_get("Bar::Foo")`.

Please note that if `Module.const_get('Bar::Foo')` doesn't find the class then it will raise exception. While, `Object.const_defined?('Foo')` will return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to see if a class was loaded at runtime:

```
def class_exists?(class_name)
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) {|c| return true if c.to_s == class_name }
  false
end
```

Comment: I used this method because in my scenario I didn't know if the constant had been previously created, and it was important that it only compared against Class objects. Being able to just pass in a string was perfect. Thanks for sharing you helped me out heaps, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me, maybe because my code lives in the scope of a submodule.

I settled on creating a `class_exists?` method in my module, using code found in [Fred Wilmore's reply to "How do I check if a class is defined?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453213/766301) and finally stopped cursing.

```
def class_exists?(name)
   name.constantize.is_a?(Class) rescue false # rubocop:disable Style/RescueModifier
end
```

Full code, for the curious:

```
module Some
  module Thing
    def self.build(object)
      name = "Some::Thing::#{object.class.name}"
      class_exists?(name) ? name.constantize.new(object) : Base.new(object)
    end

    def self.class_exists?(name)
      name.constantize.is_a?(Class) rescue false # rubocop:disable Style/RescueModifier
    end

    private_class_method :class_exists?
  end
end
```

I use it as a factory which builds objects depending on the class of the object passed as argument:

```
Some::Thing.build(something)
=> # A Some::Thing::Base object
Some::Thing.build(something_else)
=> # Another object, which inherits from Some::Thing::Base
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll take some action if the class is not loaded.

If you mean to require a file, why not just check the output of `require`?

```
require 'already/loaded'  
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something packaged, the [`finishing_moves`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves) gem adds a [`class_exists?`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves/wiki/Kernel#kernelclass_exists) method.

```
class_exists? :Symbol
# => true
class_exists? :Rails
# => true in a Rails app
class_exists? :NonexistentClass
# => false
```