# Initializing classes with Object.const_get and .send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a method that will both initialize (`.new(...`) and call a `.run` method on a class found from a string that will replace lots of duplicate code. This is the old, working method (there are lots of them similar):

```
def facebook
  @share = params[:share_document]
  ::Documents::SendToFacebook.new(@document, @share).run
end
```

The new "meta-" method looks like this:

```
def send_to_provider
  provider = params[:provider]
  @share = params[:share_document] || nil
  klass = "send_to_#{provider}".classify
  p = class_send(klass, :new, @document, @share)
  return true if p.run
end
```

And the `class_send` (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758464/ruby-how-do-i-check-if-a-class-is-defined)) looks like this:

```
def class_send(class_name, method, *args)
  return nil unless Object.const_defined?(class_name)
  c = Object.const_get(class_name)
  c.send(method, *args)
  c
end
```

I can't seem to be able to access the `c` object from the `send_to_provider` method, i.e., either `p.run` can't be found of the class isn't returned properly with `c`. I have to call `:new` instead of `:run` in the `send_to_provider` method to initialize the object.

How can I both initialize and call `:run` on the object from the `send_to_provider` method?

**EDIT**

The current code gives me this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 574.9ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `run' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:98:in `send_to_provider'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Todd Agulnick's answer was helpful, but it was a namespacing issue that caused my particular problem.

This fixed the problem for me:

```
c = ::Documents.const_get(klass).new(@document, @share)
```

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

You're sending `:new` to the class and then ignoring the result, which seems wrong. And then you're returning the class and trying to call `:run` on it, which also seems wrong.

Do you mean to write instead:

```
def class_send(class_name, method, *args)
  return nil unless Object.const_defined?(class_name)
  c = Object.const_get(class_name)
  c.send(method, *args)
end
```

That doesn't explain the error message you're reporting, although I'm not sure anything does: if the value returned by the original method is `nil` (as implied by the error message), then we should have seen the `send` fail (because `nil` doesn't respond to `:new`).

Comment: I get what you're saying. I removed the `c` returning line, same result though. I guess why I'm getting `nil` is a different question.

Comment: You should try printing out the return value to see what's going on: `c.send(method, *args).tap {|object| puts object }`. Maybe your class' initializer is failing for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. No output. I guess it's not being initialised correctly, right? Can I even `.send(:new)` to initialize a class?

Comment: Eugh, **namespacing** error, ha. Works with `c = ::Documents.const_get(klass).new(@document, @share)`

Comment: Ha! The thought about namepspace passed through my head when I first looked at your question, but then disappeared when I noticed the other problem. Good catch.