# What's the proper way to check if a constant is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a string and I just want to check if it's a "model"... so after searching I found a way:

```
'any_name'.classify.constantize
```

But... when it isn't a valid model name, it throws the following error:

> NameError (wrong constant name AnyName):

So I tried to do the following:

```
if Object.const_defined?('AnyName')
  #...
end

# I also tried this:
Object.const_get('AnyName')
```

But again, both of the options above returns the same error:

> NameError (wrong constant name AnyName):

The `const_defined` wasn't supposed to return only true/false instead of throw an error?

Currently, I have found this ugly workaround:

```
'any_name'.classify.constantize rescue nil
```

But AFAIK it isn't considered a good practice (also rubocop is claiming about this).

So, my question is... is there a safe way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is method **safe_constantize**  that can help you, it will return nil in case not defined

```
"ModelName".classify.safe_constantize
```

this is link for [safe_constantize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/safe_constantize)

Comment: Thanks. That's what exactly what I want :) Btw, can you tell me why `Object.const_defined?` is returning me errors instead of simply `true/false`?

Comment: this link can explain better for your question .const_defined? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758492/938947