# Why does defined?(ModelName) return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, defined

I ran a rails console in development mode and tested to see if a model is defined.  The results were surprising.

```
> defined?(User)
nil
> defined?(Object)
"constant"
> User
User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
> defined?(User)
"constant"
```

It looks like the `User` model is not being loaded until I directly reference it.  I'm assuming this relates to the autoloading feature so that live changes to code are reflected in the app without having to restart the server.  However, this is not ideal for the sake of checking for a model's existing.

The reason I'm checking for a model's existence is for the sake of performing some attribute population in a migration for a new column.  I only want to perform the population if the model exists because at some point in the future, the model might not exist, and it is not considered good practice to change a migration file once it has already been run.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Foo rescue false)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer will help with your issue: [How to check if a class already exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187089/how-do-i-check-if-a-class-already-exists-in-ruby)

That said, you might consider doing your attribute population outside of your migration. For example, in a rake task that you can run after deploy. I've found it saves a lot of headache to separate database schema migrations from data migrations in this fashion.